Counter Circuit can config max value using 74LS192
I have a project that design a counter circuit from 00->99 using 74LS192 and can config max value using switch. But I dont know  how to set max value. Please help me. Thanks
Example: If I choose max is 79 so it count to 79 and reset to 00.

